# Error: Cannot enable the location service. TypeError: Cannot read property 'Accuracy' of undefined

Tags: geolocation, nativescript, nativescript-vue

I'm trying to use [@nativescript/geolocation](https://docs.nativescript.org/plugins/geolocation.html) in [nativescript-vue](https://nativescript-vue.org/) android app. By calling the getCurrentLocation method as shown in the code below.

```js
import * as geolocation from '@nativescript/geolocation'
import { CoreTypes } from '@nativescript/core'
CoreTypes.Accuracy // used to describe at what accuracy the location should be get
```

```js
...
methods: {
    onLoaded(){
        console.log('>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> : loaded ')
        geolocation.getCurrentLocation({
            desiredAccuracy: Accuracy.high,
            maximumAge: 5000,
            timeout: 20000
        })
        .then(res => {
            console.log('LOACATION >>>>>>>>>>.>>>>> : ', res)
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log('LOACATION ERROR >>>>.>>>>> : ', err)
        })
    }
}
```

I get this error : `Error: Cannot enable the location service. TypeError: Cannot read property 'Accuracy' of undefined`

I also try to use `tns-core-modules` instead of '@nativescript/core'

```js
import { Accuracy } from "tns-core-modules/ui/enums";
```

But it doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone still looking for a solution to this, I was able to find was using `CoreTypes.Accuracy.high`

```
geolocation.getCurrentLocation({
            desiredAccuracy: CoreTypes.Accuracy.high,
            maximumAge: 5000,
            timeout: 20000
        })
```

The number value of high also equals `3`.
So `desiredAccuracy: 3` is also valid

Answer (score 2):

As suggested in one of the previous answer, you can directly mention desiredAcccuracy as 3, and make sure you are using correct version of location dependency in your app.gradle. (21.0.0 latest stable version)

```
dependencies {
 // compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.+'
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:21.0.0'
//  implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
}
```